# Commerce PowerShell Error SQL Provider is not installed

Tags: powershell, commerce-server

HI I'm trying to install Sitecore Experience Commerce and got this PowerShell message
I tried the steps below to install this SQL for PowerShell but I still got the error message below
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/download-sql-server-ps-module?view=sql-server-2017

Thanks for any help !

----- DeployCommerceDatabase : DeployCommerceDatabase ------------------------
Deleting existing CommerceServices databases...
Install-SitecoreConfiguration : **SQL Server Provider for Windows PowerShell is not installed.**
At F:\SITECORE_ECommerce_9\SIF.Sitecore.Commerce.1.0.1748\MyDeploy-Sitecore-Commerce.ps1:74 char:2
+     Install-SitecoreConfiguration @params
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration

[image]

Comment: Which version of Sitecore and Sitecore Commerce are you trying to install? Which OS do you use and also what is MS SQL Server version?

Comment: Windows 10, SIF.Sitecore.Commerce.1.0.1748(Ecommerce 9), SQL Server 2017 , one thing that is weird, Is that im Using PowerShell 64 bits, but when I Install, the SQLServer package goes to (C:\Program Files (x86)\WindowsPowerShell\Modules , Perhaps it should go to C:\Program Files \WindowsPowerShell\Modules

Comment: @Jose SQL Server 2017 is not supported https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/087164

Comment: I have Sitecore 9 under SQL server 2017

Comment: Yes but officially it is not supported as @Vlad mentioned therefore if you have any problems in the future Sitecore Support won't help you and also you will have problem on Slack channel or here in StackExchange to find somebody with this "exotic" configuration... You should always follow official guidelines from Sitecore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the Answer ,download the file below only if you have  "SQL SERVER 2017"

https://gitlab.com/viet.hoang/workshop/raw/master/Scripts%20for%20Sitecore%20Commerce%20901/DeployCommerceDatabase.psm1

Overwrite this file on the installation
SIF.Sitecore.Commerce.1.0.1748\Modules\DeployCommerceDatabase\DeployCommerceDatabase.psm1
Run the script to Install again and the issue will not show up