# SQL Provider for PowerShell is not installed error

Tags: sitecore-commerce, powershell

I am trying to install sitecore commerce on server where SQL server is not installed.

I got the below error
----- DeployCommerceDatabase : DeployCommerceDatabase ------------------------ Creating CommerceServices databases... Install-SitecoreConfiguration : SQL Server Provider for Windows PowerShell is not installed. At

I have looked at the [Commerce PowerShell Error SQL Provider is not installed](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/12391/commerce-powershell-error-sql-provider-is-not-installed) but my SQL server is 2016 and the answer did not help me.

[image]

Any help is appreciated

Comment: may this is useful for you : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/download-sql-server-ps-module?view=sql-server-2016

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how i end up fixing this issue

1. Install the powershell module on the server using **Install-Module -Name SqlServer**
2. Download the following from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52676 and install in order

   1. SQLSysClrTypes
   2. SharedManagementObjects
   3. PowerShellTools

Make sure it is installed and listed on HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.sqlps

[image]